# A hint on how to prove that if $(M,d)$ is complete then $M$ is closed.

Tags: metric-spaces

I would like to recieve a hint on how to get started with a proof on

> $M \subset X$ and $(M,d)$ is complete then $M$ is closed

I highly believe that there are alot of proofs regarding the above, but I'm afraid that if I google it I will be exposed to a solution, and I only want a hint, so that I can get started. ¨

This is the information I have been given:

- What a metric space is.
- Def. of convergent seq. in metric space.
- Def. of Cauchy seq. in metric space.
- A metric space $(X,d)$ is called complete if every Cachy seq. is convergent.
- If $d'$ is a metric equivalent to $d$ then $(X,d)$ is complete iff $(X,d')$ is complete.
- What an open ball is.
- An closed set is the complement of an open set.
- What an open set is.

Comment: If $M$ is complete then every limit point of $M$ is inside $M$, so $M$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with that definition (We have not gone through it) @HenryW.

Comment: I realise that my first draft of my question was bad, but I have made an update. @HenryW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's show that the complement $U=X\setminus M$ of $M$ is open. Suppose $x\in U$ and that no open ball with center $x$ is contained in $U$.

In particular, for any integer $n>0$ there is $x_n\in B(x,1/n)$ (the ball with center $x$ and radius $1/n$) such that $x_n\notin U$, that is, $x_n\in M$.

Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Since it is a sequence in $M$, it should converge to a point in $M$. But it converges to $x\notin M$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: every converging sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I just want to make sure, that you have seen my edit, before posting this answer. "The only defintion of a closed set I have is that, a closed set is the complement of an open set." Perhaps that is not a problem regarding your hint.

Comment: Completness is related to sequences, so sooner or later you need to take a look at sequentially closed subspaces..

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in X \setminus M$.  If $X \setminus M$ is not open, then for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ $B(x, \frac{1}{n})$ meets $X \setminus M$ at a point other than $x$ (say $x_n$).  Thus we have a convergent sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in $M$ with $\lim_n x_n \notin M$, hence $M$ is not complete.